# Should arguments.slice() work in ES5?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-3

I'm watching [Crockford on Javascript - Act III: Function the Ultimate](https://youtu.be/ya4UHuXNygM?t=41m26s) at around 41 mins 26 seconds. The code on his screen uses `arguments.slice()` in a way that [causes an error](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/mpvv2hc4/) for me.

```
function curry(func){
    var args = arguments.slice(1);
    ...
}
```

He explains it like this:

> I'll first get an array of arguments, except the first one, because
>   the first one is a function and I don't need that one. In this case
>   I'm assuming I'm on ES5, so I'm not doing the awful
>   `Array.prototype.apply()` trick.

The problem is that running `arguments.slice()` results in this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: arguments.slice is not a function`

I'm testing on modern browsers that definitely have ES5! The only way I can get the code to work is if I use some "awful" tricks, (as he calls them) e.g. `Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, [1])` or `[].slice.call(arguments, 1);`.

Is he just mistaken? Does his slide have a typo in it? Why doesn't `arguments.slice()` work in my ES5 browsers?

Comment: That should be a mistake.

Comment: It's hard to research in negative space, but from all I can tell he's wrong. ES6, *possibly*. It's pointless either way though, because of a recommendation from Mozilla: "*You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in JavaScript engines (V8 for example). Instead, try constructing a new array by iterating through the arguments object.*"

Comment: I cannot find any reference to `arguments.slice` in the [_ES6 Draft_](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arguments-exotic-objects) so I don't believe this is correct code, but you can enable the method manually `(function () {
    Object.getPrototypeOf(arguments).slice = Array.prototype.slice;
}());`

Comment: The answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13189828

Comment: Thanks @FabrícioMatté! Put this in an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - how does that dup answer the actual question about what Crockford is using that actually works?

Comment: Seeing as the answer linked above is from a TC39 member (the committee which governs the development of the ECMAScript/JavaScript language) and explains the historical reasons behind why Crockford expected `arguments.slice` to be in ES5, I'd feel bad quoting/borrowing too much from it hence I chose to cast a close vote as the linked answer already answers the question. `;)`

Comment: @jfriend00 (see comment above)

Comment: @jfriend00 oh, there's also a meta discussion about whether different questions which have the same answer should be considered dupes or not. IIRC, they should. I'll look it up on meta.

Comment: @jfriend00 after some search around MSO/MSE I can find rather contracting answers, so as this question is sufficiently different I guess it is worth the benefit of doubt. Reopening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13189828/1331430) TC39 member Allen Wirfs-Brock:

> Until very late in the development of ECMAScript 5, argument object were going to inherit all of the Array.prototype methods. But the "final draft" of ES5 approved by TC39 in Sept. 2009 did not have this feature.

Making the arguments object inherit from the Array prototype was actually planned, but when put in practice it [broke the web](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es5-discuss/2009-August/003112.html). Hence it was removed from the final revision before official publication.

---

Nowadays, with ECMAScript 2015 (a.k.a. ES6) standardized, the best approach is to use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
function curry(func, ...args) {
  // ...
}
```

Which is equivalent to ES5:

```
function curry(func) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
  // ...
}
```

This feature is already natively available in Firefox and Edge, and available everywhere if you use a JavaScript compiler such as [Babel](http://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Literally the same answer as mine but mine got downvoted.

Comment: @SebastianNette because you just followed his link and poorly copy/pasted what you found there.

Comment: @SebastianNette Stack Overflow voters are rather skeptic at times. I also have answers to some questions which I believe to be the best answer and yet are sunk with downvotes. Either way, voting is an anonymous process so we can only guess the reasons. brentonstrine has posed a plausible reason.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté Thanks for explaining that to me. I'm fairly new to SO and just recently started answering question so it''s sometimes really confusing why people downvote on answer and upvote an other.

Comment: @SebastianNette Yours was downvoted because for the first 20 minutes of its existence it was answering a completely different question. Now that I've seen your edit, I've removed my downvote, but it's unlikely the other voters will return and see it.

Answer (score 0):

As `arguments` is an array-like, you can use:

```
function fn() {
  const args = Array.from(arguments)
}
```

(if you have a [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) or [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/))

Answer (score -2):

The `arguments` object is not an Array. It is similar to an Array (Array like), but does not have any Array properties except `length`.

You will have to convert it to an array first using said tricks.

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
function curry(func){
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 1); // converts into array
}
```

arguments were going to inherit all prototypal methods from arrays but in the final draft this feature was removed.

https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es5-discuss/2009-August/003112.html

> I implement the logic to make the Arguments object inherit from Array
>   in WebKit last friday and it's quickly turned up a severe
>   incompatibility with Prototype.js
>   ...
>   This breaks at the very least a number of Apple sites and Nasa.gov --
>   ...
>   Due to these site breakages, caused by a major compatibility problem
>   in a fairly major library it seems infeasible to attempt to retrofit
>   array like behaviour onto arguments.

So in the end, instead of forcing everyone to change their code to avoid breaking webpages, they reverted this change. So even in ES5, you still need to apply above stated trick to convert arguments into an actual array.

Comment: Yes, the OP knows that `arguments` is not an array. The question is about why Mr Crockford explicitly states that he can use `.slice()` directly on `arguments` where his explanation is that he is assuming ES5 - even though in practice this doesn't actually work.